# Congruence mod 4 in quadratic number fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Over $\mathbb{Z}$, the congruence $e_1^4 + 2e_2^2 \equiv e_1^2 - 2e_2 \mod 4$ holds for any $e_1,e_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, e.g. by consideration of residue classes for $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Is there a $D = \sqrt{d}$ if $d = 2,3 \mod 4$ and $D = \frac{\sqrt{d}+1}{2}$ if $d = 1 \mod 4$ such that the same congruence holds in the ring of algebraic integers of the quadratic number field $\mathbb{Z}[D] \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$?

Edit: Also, can we find such a quadratic number field where the congruence holds, in which $2$ is prime in the corresponding ring of algebraic integers? Is this necessary for the congruence to hold?

Comment: Are you sure this equation holds for any $e_1,e_2\in\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Yes, it holds for any two integers (of course everything is taken mod 4)

Comment: It holds iff $O_K/(4)\cong \Bbb{Z}/(4)$ ie. $d\equiv 1\bmod 8$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks, is there a standard text or reference I could use to see why what you say is true? So far I was able to find using the book on ANT by Samuel, in Chapter 3, that $\text{card}(A / Ax) = N(x)$ where $A$ is the ring of algebraic integers of some algebraic number field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. But then I don't see why $\text{card}(\mathcal{O}_K / 4 \mathcal{O}_K) = 4$ using this result. Here $N$ is supposedly the norm.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that even if I were to narrow this down to a cardinality of 4, I need to exclude $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Comment: @reuns I seem to only be able to get $\mathcal{O}_{K} / (4) \equiv (\mathbb{Z}_{4})^2$, but in any case, shouldn't the identity still hold, since it holds component wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d\equiv1\bmod8$ then the congruence certainly holds. In that case, $\frac12(1+\sqrt{d})$ reduces to a $2$-adic integer, and thus the integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ reduce to ordinary integers $\bmod 4$.

Note that this includes $d=-7$ where $2$ is not prime, for $2=[\frac12(1+\sqrt{-7})][\frac12(1-\sqrt{-7})]$. Any case where $d$ is eight less than an odd square similarly renders $2$ non-prime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I understand correctly, are you saying that the $d=-7$ case is exceptional among $d \equiv 1 \mod 8$ in the sense that $2$ is not prime? If say $d = 17$, would $2$ still be non-prime?

Comment: The case $d=-7$ is unique only for negative discriminants. Any positive $d$ eight less than an odd square will also make $2$ non-prime, for example $2=[\frac12(5+\sqrt{17})][\frac12(5-\sqrt{17})]$; also $d=41,73,113,...$.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt reply, just to make sure I follow, it is the case that for $d < 0$ and $d \equiv 1 \mod 8$, the only situation in which $2$ is non-prime happens to be $d = -7$, so in all other cases, e.g. $d = -15$, $2$ is in fact prime? Also may I know of a reference to prove these statements for myself if you do not have the time to include a proof (I am quite naive on this topic).

Comment: My "reference" is to render $2=[\frac12(2n-1+\sqrt{4n^2-4n-7})][\frac12(2n-1-\sqrt{4n^2-4n-7})]$, where $n$ is a natural number and $4n^2-4n-7$ represents eight less than the odd square $(2n-1)^2$.

Comment: I see, but why does this preclude $2$ being non-prime for negative $d$ less than $-7$?  Couldn't $2$ be non-prime but irreducible in non UFD cases? Or in other words why does this preclude $2$ being non-prime in other cases? (It seems sufficient but I don't understand where the necessity part is coming from)